# Importing all classes from a library in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular problem and need to import several classes from a library. I'll illustrate this with an example. Suppose I'm making a library of foods. The library directory looks like this for now:

foods:

- apple
- bagel
- chips

(Assume each food has a corresponding .ts file with the class being the name of the component.)

Now, I want to import all the foods. I could do the following:

```
import { Apple } from 'foods/apple';
import { Bagel } from 'foods/bagel';
import { Chips } from 'foods/chips';
```

But I want to know if there's a way to import several of these at once like this:

```
import { Apple, Bagel, Chips } from 'foods/*';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Barrel](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/barrel.html):

> A barrel is a way to rollup exports from several modules into a single
>   convenient module. The barrel itself is a module file that re-exports
>   selected exports of other modules.

## Example:

**myfoods.ts** (just pick a name)

```
export * from 'food/apple'; // * if you want to export all from 'apple'
export { Bagel } from 'foods/bagel';
export { Chips } from 'foods/chips';
```

**your component**

```
import { Apple, Bagel, Chips } from './myfoods';
```

You can also create a file called `index.ts` and then it is implicit when you just refer to the folder name.

- myfoods

  - index.ts
- app.module.ts

**index.ts**

```
// same logic as myfoods.ts
export * from 'food/apple'; // * if you want to export all from 'apple'
export { Bagel } from 'foods/bagel';
export { Chips } from 'foods/chips';
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Apple, Bagel, Chips } from './myfoods'; // index is implicitly assumed
```

Thanks to @Phix for the link to the [Barrel](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/barrel.html) documentation.

Comment: If the `index.ts` file is in the `foods` directory (noted by the import from `./foods`), wouldn't the imports be like `./bagel` instead of `foods/bagel`?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel That's what I meant with my comment I just removed. However, I made it more clear now.

Comment: Just to add a tiny bit this is called a [barrel](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/barrel.html).

Comment: @Phix Thanks for the link. I have added it to my answer.